# Spring Oauth2 not working on JBOSS 6.10 enterprise

Tags: spring, spring-security, jboss, oauth-2.0

I tested the Sparklr demo for Spring OAuth 2 on this server Jboss Enterprise 6.1.0 and I get a 404 for /oauth/token. The same war works great on tomcat 8, get a token back no problem.

Do you know how I can fix this server to work with Spring OAuth 2? Or why the same war behaves differently on the two different servers?

Here is the source for the Sparklr demo. 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples/oauth2/sparklr

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on the new Jboss EAP 7.10 and Sparklr demo is working great. Fortunately we upgraded the jboss and this fixed it.